# How to re-select value from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have Ajax live search script it has few text input can search products.
The live search function works great. and I have a question:

> If I would like to change one of product name How to go back before
>   page and re-select the product?

I tyred re-select diffrent one but it still same product which I select first time.

This is my first time ajax and JSON script. Could someone teach me please.

index.php

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="" class="form-control" size="3000" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
<span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
<ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#state').val('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('js/data.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1) {
                    //$('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');

                    $('#result').append(
                        '<li class="list-group-item link-class"' +
                        ' data-name="' + value.name + '"' +
                        ' data-code="' + value.code + '"' +
                        ' data-location="' + value.location + '"' +
                        '><img src="' + value.image + '" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> ' + value.name + ' <span class="text-muted">' + value.location + '</span></li>');
                }
            });
        });
    });

    $('#result').on('click', 'li', function () {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        var code = $(this).data('code');
        var location = $(this).data('location');

        var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
        $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));

        $('#search').attr('readonly', true);

        $("#result").html('');

        $('#result').after('<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' + name + '">');
        $('#result').after('<input type="hidden" name="code" value="' + code + '">');
        $('#result').after('<input type="hidden" name="location" value="' + location + '">');
```

This is second live search JS file

```
$('#result2').append(
'<li class="list-group-item link-class"' +
' data-name="' + value.name + '"' + 
' data-code="' + value.code + '"' +  
' data-location="' + value.location + '"' + 
'><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+'  <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
}
});
});
});

$('#result2').on('click', 'li', function() {
var name = $(this).data('name' ); 
var code = $(this).data('code' ); 
var location = $(this).data('location' ); 
//alert( name2 + ', ' + code2 + ', ' + location2 ); 

var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
$('#search2').val($.trim(click_text[0]));


$('#search2').attr('readonly',true); 


$("#result2").html('');


$('#result2').after('<input type="hidden" name="name2" value="'+name2+'">');
$('#result2').after('<input type="hidden" name="code2" value="'+code2+'">');
$('#result2').after('<input type="hidden" name="location2" value="'+location2+'">');


});
});
```

JSON file

```
[
{ "name":"orangecar","code": "102","location":"34" },
{ "name":"applecar","code": "101","location":"12" },
{ "name":"bananacar","code": "202","location":"58" },
{ "name":"limecar","code": "201","location":"63" }
]
```

Comment: If the `JSON` source is the same always I would recomend that you load it only once and save it as an object, that way you don't execute the same call on every `keyUp` event, if you can provide a fiddle with your code I could help you with that

Comment: Dear @Sabbin Thank you for helping me. Yes. JSON is always same. I'm very beiginer so I don't know what to fix it about KeyUp. I will add 2nd search section thatI just combined that is so garrulous I guess haha.

Comment: if you can create a fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/ - with the HTML code and the full jQuery code, I can help you organize the jQuery part and the logic for the search

Comment: Dear @Sabbin Thank you so much ! jsfiddle I never used it before it works good ? https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/7kmjh6cd/4/ and I wonder how can I put JSON code ?

Comment: Dear @Sabbin I add JSON file here. I'm so happy you doig so nice to me

Comment: I'll resolve your fiddle and come back with a response

Comment: Dear @Sabbin Thank you so much!!! I'm tesing right now Could you wait for me a while .

Comment: Dear @Sabbin WOW this is amazing!! it become way faster! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Please check the response, it should help you get the data from the file

Comment: Dear @Sabbin Thank you very much at yesterday.  I tried my main pc. about your first code that really fast item show up but it can only re-select 2nd live search. 1st live search is same. So then I tryed your final code you posted jsfiddl. i used whole js code but i didnt work even live search function. I tryed to chage little bit for work but I just couldn't becase of my poor understand ...Actually I have 3 live search text area. I won't make it for Three so could you teach me again please. 3rd text inut is all same without  name="search3" id="search3 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188056/discussion-between-sabbin-and-blueink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({
       cache: false
   });
   JSONdata = await getJson(); //JSONdata is a global variable which you can access from everywhere
});

getJson = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.getJSON('js/data.json', (data) => {
        resolve(data);
    }).fail(function() {
        reject([]);
    })
});
```

This is the part that handle your `JSON` call and sets the data in the `JSONdata` global variable. In case it the `$.getJson` fails it returns an empty array... After that you can use `JSONdata` anywhere in your app.

I also updated the fiddle, you should check what the rest of the code works, the `JSON` load part is done.

**LE: Updated the script add added requested features**

```js
$(document).ready(async function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  JSONdata = await getJson(); //JSONdata is a global variable which you can access from everywhere
  generateFields(20);

});

$(document).on('keyup', '.search', function() {
  const ref = $(this).attr('data-ref');

  $(`.resultUl[data-ref="${ref}"]`).html('');
  const searchField = $(this).val();
  const expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

  $.each(JSONdata, (key, value) => {
    const {
      name,
      location,
      code,
      image
    } = value;
    if (name.search(expression) != -1 || location.search(expression) != -1) {
      $(`.resultUl[data-ref="${ref}"]`).append(
        `<li 
          class="list-group-item link-class"
         data-name="${name}"
          data-code="${code}"
         data-location="${location}"
        >
         <img src="${image}" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" />
         ${name}
          <span class="text-muted">${location}</span>
         </li>`
      );
    }
  });
});

getJson = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Change the path below with the path for your script
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/lpizs', (data) => {
    resolve(data);
  }).fail(function() {
    reject([]);
  })
});

generateFields = (fieldNumber) => {
  Array(fieldNumber).fill().map((v, i) => {
    const ref = i + 1;
    $('#container').append(
      `<div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="btn-group">
     <input type="text" class="search" data-ref="${ref}" placeholder="製品 その１" class="form-control" size="3000" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
     <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group resultUl" data-ref="${ref}"></ul>
    </div>`
    )
  });
}
```

```css
.fieldContainer {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

This should work properly with your app

Comment: Thank you This is amazing! Sorry I can't try out your code right now because my main pc is diffrenct so.... I will report tomorrow. Thank you for Everything! I will send a message tomorrow!

Comment: Dear @Sabbin I just send message to you. Sorry my poor understanding I couldn't add your this code to my js file yet. Could you post whole js code include this at jsfiddle ? I'm beginer so my brain takes more time to understand your great explain. so now I won't make good to add your this code to whole js file so.

Comment: please give me the link for the fiddle here so I can check

Comment: Dear @Sabbin Hi. Thank you. here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/7kmjh6cd/5/

Comment: I don't see any modifications in the fiddle since yesterday, please explain to me the desired result. You need to have 3 selects in the page with the same data source?(the JSON)

Comment: I tried your code at my local searver(laravel) Not fiddle. becase i need to see the name show up from JSON. First of all I copyed your fist code to my js file  as I told you your first code fixing around keyUp. that works great it become really fast! so then. next i copyed your whole js code and past it my js file but result is both live search function didn't work. 
when I see you code around line 50 , 51 and last 75 }); has error at my sublime text. I don't touch nothing but live search didn't work so I adjust little bit like remove the above point but still didn't work.

Comment: Dear @Sabbin I'm sorry am I explaing well? I add 3rd search section this is my laravel top page code https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/7kmjh6cd/13/

Comment: Dear @Sabbin Hi. I'm in chat room. I'm waiting for you.